# Redirect development website to main website via .htacess

Tags: web, redirect, dns

Please help me to redirect my testing site to root website via htaccess rules. I want to redirect https://example.com/staging/ to https://example.com/

```
Redirect https://example.com/staging/ ~ https://example.com
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there anyone who can suggest any solution for this........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @webesters please try this code in htaccess file of your root directory

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^staging/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302,NE]

Comment: dear sir @Campy, it is working thanks for the help.